# How to show all subcategories on all the pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show a menu with all subcategories of a current parent category, but not the parent category. Looks simple, but I'cant remove the parent names, or show subcategories in a single post.

This is the code that I'm currently using

```
<?php if (is_front_page() or is_single() ) { ?>

        <?php } else { ?>

             <?php
             if (is_category() ) {
                $this_category = get_category($cat);
             }
             ?>
             <?php
             if($this_category->category_parent)
                $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1');

                else
                $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=1&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
                    if ($this_category) { ?> 
                    <ul>
                    <?php echo $this_category; ?>
                    </ul>

                <?php } ?>



<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code in where you want to display child categories

```
$args = array('child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID);
$categories = get_categories( $args );

echo "<ul>";
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo "<li>".$category->name."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>"
```

Tested and it works well.

Comment: Thank you @raju_eww I just tested and there are some issues. 1.- The code display the name of the parent categories, this only have to display subcategories. 2.- The LI don't show the automatic wordpress classes (I tried adding 'implode', but i can't display them. 3.- How to get the permalinks of the categories?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the all the subcategories of parent one using `get_terms($taxonomies, $args);`

First of all declare your taxonomies like below:

```
$taxonomies = array( 
    'category',
);
```

Now you just need to pass `$args` parameter in `get_terms` function like below;

```
$args = array(
    'parent'         => $parent_term_id, // You can use parent id here
); 

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
```

This way you will get the all subcategories of applied `$parent_term_id` in `$args`

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you @Gajjar Chintan. Could you show me that in an example? I'm newby and I just try your snippet but I'm can't show any category.

Comment: Just try to use $termchildren = get_terms('product_cat',array('child_of' => $parent_id));  Where replace product_cat with your texonomy name & parent_id with $parent_id. Use correct texonomy name & parent id in code.

Comment: I return only "array" word. 

<?php
    $parent_id = get_category($cat);
    $taxonomies = array( 
    'category',
    );
    $args = array(
    'parent'         => $parent_term_id, // You can use parent id here
    ); 

    $terms = get_terms('$taxonomies',array('child_of' => $parent_id));
    ?>
         
                    <ul>
                    <?php echo $terms; ?>
                    </ul>

    
       
    <?php } ?>

Comment: Apologies for ask again @GajjarChintan, but could you construct and example?